# Can't find solution for equation

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

$100z=a(z+i)(z-i)^2(z-2)+b(z-i)^2(z-2)+c(z+i)^2(z-i)(z-2)+d(z+i)^2(z-2)+e(z+i)^2(z-i)^2$

I already got $b=5+10i, d=-5+10i $ and $e =8$ by eliminating the factors using $z=i, z=-i, z=-2$ but I cant get $a$ and $c$ with that method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you still want to use the same method? or else you may write the equation as $Az^4+Bz^3+Cz^2+Dz+E=0$, and then you may solve five equations $A=B=C=D=E=0$ to find five unknowns. As you already know three unknowns, other two can be found using this method. Further, your solutions may be incorrect, e.g., when I substitute $z=i$, I got $d=\frac{25}{(i-2) i}$. Double check if you make some typos.

Comment: @Frey your d is the same as my d. I do know the method with the linear system. But the professor says I have to use this method. It seems better suiting, too. But these last two variables... I checked for typos but I found none.

Answer (score 1):

$100z=a(z+i)(z-i)^2(z-2)+b(z-i)^2(z-2)+c(z+i)^2(z-i)(z-2)+d(z+i)^2(z-2)+e(z+i)^2(z-i)^2$

Setting $z=i$ gives 
$$100i=d(i+i)^2(i-2)\quad\Rightarrow\quad d=-5+10i$$

Setting$z=-i$ gives
$$100(-i)=b(-i-i)^2(-i-2)\quad\Rightarrow\quad b=\color{red}{-}5\color{red}{-}10i$$

Setting $z=\color{red}{+}2$ gives
$$100\cdot 2=e(2+i)^2(2-i)^2\quad\Rightarrow\quad e=8$$

Setting $z=0$ gives
$$\begin{align}&0=ai(-i)^2(-2)+b(-i)^2(-2)+ci^2(-i)(-2)+di^2(-2)+ei^2(-i)^2\\&\Rightarrow 0=2ai+2b-2ci+2d+e\\&\Rightarrow 0=2ai+2(-5-10i)-2ci+2(-5+10i)+8\\&\Rightarrow c=a+6i\tag1\end{align}$$

Setting $z=1$ gives
$$\begin{align}&100=-a(1+i)(1-i)^2-b(1-i)^2-c(1+i)^2(1-i)-d(1+i)^2+e(1+i)^2(1-i)^2\\&\Rightarrow 50=-a(1-i)-b(-i)-c(1+i)-di+2e\\&\Rightarrow 50=-a(1-i)-(-5-10i)(-i)-c(1+i)-(-5+10i)i+16\\&\Rightarrow a(-1+i)+c(-1-i)=14\tag2\end{align}$$

From $(1)(2)$,
$$a(-1+i)+(a+6i)(-1-i)=14\quad\Rightarrow \quad a=-4-3i,\quad c=-4+3i.$$